# ViewPager + ListFragment calling setEmptyText(...) causes IllegalStateException

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-listfragment

I have a `ViewPager` which contains a series of `ListFragments`.

```
    _viewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentPagerAdapter(this.getChildFragmentManager()) {
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int i) {
            ListFragment lf = new ListFragment();
            lf.setListAdapter(new MyAdapter());
            lf.setEmptyText("Empty"); // <-- crash on this line

            return lf;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return _myData.size();
        }
    });
```

I want my `ListFragments` to display an empty message when empty, so I tried calling `setEmptyText(...)`, but this throws an exception:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content view not yet created`

How am I supposed to set the empty text for my ListFragments if I can't do it here?

Comment: In ListFragment `onViewCreated()` method.

Comment: I didn't write ListFragment. Are saying I have to override the class in order to call a public method? That simply cannot be true. Why would setEmptyText be public if it can only be called by a subclass?

Comment: I am having the same problem. I am using a `ListFragment` and my app is crashing with a NullPointerException when there's no data (if I comment out the `setListAdapter()` call it doesn't crash).

I've tried overriding `onViewCreated()` and calling `setEmptyText()` but that doesn't seem to do anything; I still just see a blank white screen with that circular animated progress icon going and my FloatingActionButton.

I didn't use ListFragments in a previous app I've done; I should just go back to doing everything manually. What a pain in the ass.

Comment: @mtmurdock have you resolve this problem? I just match this... it's so weird...